# Apache Camel rest component: Address already used when trying to consume a service

Tags: rest, apache-camel, quarkus

I have a rest service listening on an endpoint and I'm trying to consume it via the following Camel route:

```
from("file:...")
...
to("rest://post:api?host=localhost:8080&...")
```

However, running this route produces the following exception:

```
2020-07-24 18:59:27,592 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Error running Quarkus application: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:601)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:90)
at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:90)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:61)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:38)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:106)
at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:29)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start HTTP server
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.doServerStart(VertxHttpRecorder.java:432)
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.startServer(VertxHttpRecorder.java:198)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.VertxHttpProcessor$openSocket-2064782366.deploy_0(VertxHttpProcessor$openSocket-2064782366.zig:119)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.VertxHttpProcessor$openSocket-2064782366.deploy(VertxHttpProcessor$openSocket-2064782366.zig:36)
at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:540)
... 6 more
```

I'm confused as what obviously happens is that, instead of consuming the service, the to("rest://...") tries to start a producer on the given endpoint. And since there is already a service listening on this endpoint, the exception is raised.

How can I consume this service knowing that I don't want to use http/http4 components, because I need automatic XML marshalling/unmarshalling?

Answer (score 1):

What it is failing here is quarkus and I think it is because you have quarkus-http as dependency which by default starts a web server on 8080

Comment: Right, looking carefully at the log file I see that:
2020-07-25 17:36:56,543 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) send-money-file-poller 1.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 1.5.2.Final) started in 3.189s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080